# Ошибка TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
// не изменять
$(`.stat`).append(`<div data-type="volume"><div>`);
let elem = $(`.stat [data-type="volume"]`);
// не изменять


let canvas = elem.html('<canvas></canvas>').find('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let width = canvas.offsetWidth * 2;
let height = canvas.offsetHeight * 2;

console.log(canvas, width, height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stat"></div>
```

Comment: elem.html('<canvas></canvas>'), может надо изменить на elem.createElement('canvas')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elem` - это `jQuery` объект.
[`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) - также возвращает `jQuery` объект.

У `jQuery` объектов нет метода `getContext`, поэтому и ошибка.

Для решения нужно получить `HTMLElement` из выборки `jQuery`, например с помощью метода [`.get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/), либо обращаясь просто по индексу

```
let canvas = elem.html('<canvas></canvas>').find('canvas').get(0);
let canvas = elem.html('<canvas></canvas>').find('canvas')[0];
```